# Best way to access the shared folder for a web application

Tags: iis, application-pool, virtual-directory, shared-directory

I have two machines, Machine A and Machine B in LAN connection. I have shared a folder on Machine A called "SharedFiles" by giving access to "IUSR" and "IIS USER "  and local user.

I have hosted a web application with IIS on machine B. From this hosted application , I want to access the "SharedFiles" folder.

What is the best way to access the shared folder for the web application ? I found below two options.

1. By changing the Web application's pool identity. Set a custom account for this pool identity where credentials should be the same as the shared folder or vice versa.

2. By setting up a virtual directory for this. I don't know how to use it. I have read the theory but never use it before.

If option 2 is correct then , do we need to access that folder using http/https?  How does this virtual directory work(Not looking for steps but logical flow)?

Answer (score 1):

To add the virtual directory with the shred path under your site you could follow the below steps:

1)Open iis manager.

2)Right-click on your site ->slect add a virtual directory.

[image]

3)in add virtual directory box enter any name and your share folder path

[image]

Note: Make sure you have assigned the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the shared folder.

- After doing this go back again select site.
- Double click authentication.
- Select "Anonymous authentication"
- Click edit from the action pane.

[image]

- application pool identity. click ok.

now you can access your shared folder in browser with your site bindings/virtual directory name like shown below:

[image]

you could use the iis application pool identity to the administrator or local system account.

Comment: my question is which is the best way to use shared folder for the web application and if it is virtual directory then it should be accessible via http. Is that correct way to use it ?

Comment: @kreya in my opinion we can not say this is the best way. which way is easy to use for you is the best way.